# how to write in a csv zipped columns from another csv

Tags: python, csv, zip

I want to create a csv file with zipped columns from another csv my code is

```
import csv
import itertools
f = open('comparisons_final.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
csv_out = open('test192.csv', 'wb')
mywriter= csv.writer(csv_out,delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
for row in csv_f:
    a.append(row[0])
    b.append(row[1])
    c.append(row[2])
f.close()
rows=zip(a,b,c)
mywriter.writerow(rows)
csv_out.close()
```

but i get "_csv.Error: sequence expected" what's wrong??

the first file (comparisons_final) has 9 rows and i keep 3 of them but i want them in tuples not in lists that's why i zip them.

Comment: It could be that rows is actually a generator, not a sequence - depending on your python version. But more importantly, you just seem to be recreating the original csv file

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
mywriter.writerow(rows):
```

You need:

```
for row in rows:
    mywriter.writerow(row)
```

Although I'm still not sure of your program's purpose, this just creates a copy.